# Why does the units of Range.ColumnWidth not match either points or Centimeters (default unit used)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, column-width

I am producing a VBA subroutine in an Access database which generates an Excel File however when I modify the column widths using:

```
Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = ...
```

Produces mixed results depending on the unit of measurement. Excel's default measurement set in options is Centimeters. I have tried entering the value in points and in cm but the result is either too wide or too small (see below):

```
Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 3.07 'In Centimeters - Too small
Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 87.02 'In Points - Too big
```

According to the documentation 
    `Range.ColumnWidth`
is set using the measurement in the points unit of measurement (width of 0). Regardless of the value I enter the result isn't the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The .ColumnWidth property refers to the number of zeros you can type in a cell in the default font without exceeding the cell's width.

In a new workbook where presumably your default column width is 8.43, type `'000000000` in a cell and you'll see that the 9th zero overflows the right cell border by about half a zero.

To set the cell width in points, set .ColumnWidth to `points / cell.Width * cell.ColumnWidth`. Here's the catch, you have to set it three times to get it close, but it will almost never be exact. So put the .ColumnWidth assignment in a For Next loop and set it three times.

Note that the .Width property is in points and you can't set it. The .ColumnWidth property is in crazy-zero-width-measurement and you can set it. Why it takes three times, I don't know.

See http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/06/01/column-widths-in-points/ for some test results on the 'three times' thing.

Comment: `RowHeight` is as you would expect, `ColumnWidth` is a completely unexpected, unusual and not even precise format without any warning or explanation... someone on the Excel team must have had a really cruel sense of humor back in the days. Thanks for your explanation, you saved me a headache!

Comment: I believe the "three times" thing is due to rounding issues (only two decimals being provided by the property getter of `.ColumnWidth`). If you apply your formula on a range where the width is very large, then the conversion from points to width-of-a-zero should be more accurate.